# Is there an English grammar equivalent of the Italian "complemento"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

In Italian, [translating from the Italian wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_%28linguistica%29) as accurately as I can muster,

> a "complemento" is a part of a sentence (one or more words) that specify, clarify and enrich the meaning thereof.

Italian has a [loooong, punctilious list of various possible types of "complemento"](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_%28linguistica%29#Classificazione), for example:

- I have plenty *of diamonds* — ["complemento" of abundance](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementi_di_abbondanza_e_privazione)
- I am short *of diamonds* — ["complemento" of privation](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementi_di_abbondanza_e_privazione)
- It's made *of diamonds* — ["complemento" of matter](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_di_materia)
- Some *of the diamonds* are valuable — ["complemento" of partition](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_partitivo)
- Each *of these diamonds* is valuable — ["complemento" of specification](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_di_specificazione)
- It's worthy *of diamonds* — ["complemento" of value](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_di_stima)

I can't find anything like this on the English wikipedia - although [adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_%28grammar%29) sound suspiciously similar, I'd say none of these are temporal, locative, modicative, causal, instrumental, conditional or concessive - although there certainly are some that are, and not all require prepositions:

- I'm waiting *there* - ["complemento" of being in place](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_di_stato_in_luogo)
- I'm going *there* - ["complemento" of motion to place](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_di_moto_a_luogo)
- I'm going *to Rome* - ["complemento" of motion to place](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_di_moto_a_luogo) also.

The next closest thing would be [adverbial complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_complement), but most of these aren't required for the sentence to make sense, or tied to the verb.

Comment: @drɱ65δ then they probably are adjuncts. I added preposition-less examples to make sure I didn't give the wrong idea.

Comment: All your examples are of either adjuncts *or* adverbial complements. Adverbial complements *are* required for the sentence to make sense; adjuncts aren't.

Comment: @drɱ65δ I guess then that for all the distinctions we make, the one between adjuncts and adverbial complements is one we _don't_ do. That, or I'm making the wrong examples in the attempt to make each one short. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Italian Wikipedia appears to call both complements and adjuncts *complementi*. Therefore I conclude that an Italian *complemento* is a very broad category, and it is **not** the same as an English complement. I'd call it a **[constituent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_%28linguistics%29)**. The Italian list includes both complements, like subject and object, and adjuncts, like adjuncts of time and location.

> Complementi essenziali e circostanziali

Under this sub-header, it explains that there are *complementi* that are essential (*essenziali*) to the structure of the sentence, and those that are not (*circostanziali*).

In English, a *complement* is a part that cannot be left out, while an *adjunct* (also called *satellite*) can be left out without too much fuss.

> I like *pigs*.

Here, *pigs* is the object to the verb *like*: it is essential and a complement. *I like* is not a grammatical sentence, because the object cannot be left out.

> I like pigs *sometimes*.

Here, *sometimes* is an adverbial constituent of time; it is not essential and hence an adjunct. Note that the distinction between what is essential and what isn't is not always clear: the categories *complement* and *adjunct/satellite* are by no means clear cut. There is often debate about various practical examples.

Since the Italian word seems to include both complements and adjuncts, it must signify a *constituent*, which is basically a building-block in a sentence that has its own syntactic function. The above sentence has three constituents: *I, pigs, sometimes*. Subjects and object are complements; constituents of time are mostly adjuncts (but not always).

Many of the examples in your question are adverbial; some are adverbial adjuncts, others adverbial complements. Note that adverbial constituents are usually adjuncts.

Comment: Hm, in "I like pigs", pigs would be an object, not a "complemento."

Comment: @Badp: Then how about this: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_oggetto Oggetto is also in the list on your page.

Comment: ...duh, you're right :D Sorry

Answer (score 3):

From looking at Wikipedia's page on *[adverbials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial)*, I gather that any *complemento* is also an *adverbial*; in your examples, either an *[adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct)* or an *[adverbial complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_complement)*.  Wikipedia says:

> In grammar an *adverbial* is a word (an adverb) or a group of words (an adverbial phrase or an adverbial clause) that modifies or tells us something about the sentence or the verb. The word *adverbial* is also used as an adjective, meaning 'having the same function as an adverb'. Look at the examples below:
>
> Danny speaks **fluently**. (telling us more about the verb)
>   Lorna ate breakfast **yesterday morning**.
>
> [...]
>
> Adverbials are typically divided into four classes:
>
> [adverbial complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_complement) (i.e. obligatory adverbial) are adverbials that render a sentence ungrammatical and meaningless if removed.
>
> *John put the flowers **in a vase**.*
>
> [adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct): these are part of the core meaning of the sentence, but if omitted still leave a meaningful sentence.
>
> *John helped me **with my homework**.*
>
> [conjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunct): these link two sentences together.
>
> *John helped so I was, **therefore**, able to do my homework.*
>
> [disjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct): these make comments on the meaning of the rest of the sentence.
>
> ***Surprisingly**, he passed all of his exams.*

About *adverbial complement*:

> An *adverbial complement* is an adverbial that is obligatorily subcategorized for by a verb, such that if removed, it will yield an ungrammatical sentence:
>
> - She put the cheese **back**.
> - *She put the cheese.

*Adjunct*:

> In linguistics, an adjunct is an optional, or structurally dispensable, part of a sentence that, when removed, will not affect the remainder of the sentence except to discard from it some auxiliary information.
>
> [...]
>
> An adjunct can be a single word, a phrase, or a clause.
>
> **Single word**
>
> *She will leave **tomorrow.***
>
> **Phrase**
>
> *She will leave **in the morning.***
>
> **Clause**
>
> *She will leave **after she has had breakfast.***

Answer (score 1):

In its broadest sense, a complement in English grammar is anything that completes a clause or a phrase. To that extent, it has some similarity with Italian *complemento*: in your first set of examples, *(the) diamonds* is the complement of the prepositional phrase that begins with *of*. More specifically, however, it describes, in the words of one grammarian, 'a slot in a sentence that expresses attributes of the Subject or Object.' In this sense, it is perhaps best known as a description of the words that follow a copular verb: *good* in *This looks good*, or *my destiny* in *This is my destiny*.